# Use of java.util.concurrent.Executor stops tomcat from stopping

Tags: java, web-services, spring, tomcat, concurrency

**Background:**

I need to use `java.util.concurrent.Executor` to serialize the execution of some legacy code inside a WebService.

I have added an member variable, executor, to the WebService class. It is injected from the outside by the springframework.

The executor bean is defined as such:

```
<bean id="riskValueEstimateUpdateExecutor" scope="singleton"
        class="java.util.concurrent.Executors"
        factory-method="newSingleThreadExecutor" />
```

- Tomcat version: 6.0.22
- Java version: 1.6
- spring framework: 2.5.5

**Problem:**

The WS works as expected. We rolled it out to a linux server. Then we realised the tomcat stop script could no longer stop the service.

I use kill -3 to the tomcat instance. In the thread dump I find these lines:

```
"pool-2-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0xad637c00 nid=0xf37 waiting on condition [0xae882000..0xae883020]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0xb453b710> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1925)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:358)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:946)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

How can I fix this problem?

If you need more information, please suggest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's neither Tomcat's nor Spring's fault. You just have to shutdown `ExecutorService` properly. Add `destroy-method` in bean definition:

```
<bean id="riskValueEstimateUpdateExecutor" scope="singleton"
    class="java.util.concurrent.Executors"
    factory-method="newSingleThreadExecutor" destroy-method="shutdown"/>
```

BTW `singleton` scope is default. You might also consider using `shutdownNow()` method. Also note that Spring provides powerful [task scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) mechanism.

Comment: is this the correct to use executors in tomcat/java/spring env?

Answer (score 5):

You need to find a way to call [shutdown](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) when the Spring context is shutdown: try using the bean `destroy-method` property and set that to `shutdown`. Something like this:

```
<bean id="riskValueEstimateUpdateExecutor" scope="singleton"
        class="java.util.concurrent.Executors"
        factory-method="newSingleThreadExecutor" destroy-method="shutdown" />
```

Comment: your answer is just as good! I wish I can accept your answer too.

Comment: Use a different executor: newSingleThreadExecutor is (by definition) a single thread. Checkout java.util.concurrent.Executors for alternatives.